# USB 3.1 cable only transferring at 40MB/s speeds

Tags: usb-storage, usb-c, usb-3.1-type-c

I have a WD Passport SSD with USB 3.1. With the stock cable I transfer data at 380-420MB/s. (Limited to SATA)

I purchased a 10 foot USB C 3.1 gen 2 cable.

With this new cable I only transfer data at 38-42MB/s.

I also got a replacement cable when I complained about the first one, but it also transfers at 38-42MB/s.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here or are the cables just crap? At $40 each for these cables I expect better.

Motherboard I’m transferring to/from is Z270 ROG Code with current BIOS.

Also get the same speeds transferring to my Galaxy Note 10+ USB 3.1 internal storage. The cable does charge the Note with the 45W PD2 charger super fast charge 2.0.

The cable itself is advertised as:

> USB C 3.1 Gen2 SuperSpeed 10Gbps E-Marker chip Fastest Charging USB Cable, Oculus Quest Link Compatible (White, 10 Feet)

Comment: Are you sure you're plugged into a USB 3 port?

Comment: Yeah. I have a usb 3.1 port on my motherboard and on my graphics card. I get the same speeds from both ports on my stock WD cable (380-420MB/s).

Comment: But only 38-42MB/s with these two expensive cables that claim to be usb 3.1 g2

Comment: The USB 3.2 Gen 2 (the proper name for USB 3.1 Gen 2) is connected to the front panel.  I assume you are plugging the cable into a port connected to the front panel?  BTW: **None of [these](https://www.asus.com/media/global/gallery/WKRuVk3L4Ee2fJoy_setting_000_1_90_end_500.png) ports are USB 3.2 GEN 2**  You have one USB 3.1 GEN 1 TYpe-C and one USB 3.1 GEN 1 Type-A the rest are either USB 3.0 or USB 2.0.  **I can almost guarantee you based on the speeds you are reporting, you are using the incorrect port, please try using the correct port**

Comment: "USB-C is the future-proof reversible connector — and ROG Maximus IX Code lets you put the connection right where it's needed! With an onboard USB 3.1 front panel connector you can position a USB-C port on your system's front panel, so it's always within reach. " - What this means is that **the front panel on your case must have the proper I/O**  Based on your reported speed of 400-500 MB/sec thats actually USB 3.0 speeds (5 Gbits/sec)

Comment: Note that 10ft (3m) is the hairy edge of how far 5Gbps and 10Gbps USB signaling is expected to reach with passive cables. It's probably wise to only purchase high-quality cables from trusted manufacturers if you need 10ft cables.

Comment: What @Spiff said. Even if this is a so-called “good quality” cable, the best it should be only relied on is for charging and not high-speed data transfers.

Answer (score 0):

40MBps is USB 2.0 speed.

This can mean only 2 things:

- The cable is actually USB 2.0.
- The cable is USB 3.1 but you are plugging it in on a USB 2.0 port.

If both cables are plugged into the same USB ports (on device and PC), and it works with one cable but not the other then you have the correct drivers but the cable is USB 2.0.

Comment: Thanks. The cable has all positive reviews and the owner of the company has even reached out to correct it. Its just weird how it does the 45W super fast charge 2.0 on the Note since I thought that was only a usb 3.1 possibility.

Comment: Technically USB C power requires only 1 extra wire in the cable (wired in a different position - CC1&2) as opposed to 4 or 8 extra cores for the high speed data lines: https://superuser.com/questions/1567266/howto-repair-broken-usb-c-power-delivery-cable/1567269#1567269

Comment: “The cable has all positive reviews and the owner of the company has even reached out to correct it.” I highly doubt the owner of the company reached out to do anything. You were played. Most of these fly-by-night cable manufacturers are a joke. They don’t manufacture anything; they just place labels on generic products. This is an old question, but you should have just returned the cable to the “owner” (aka: customer service person) for a full refund and that’s that.